# Prove two equalities about the Cauchy projectors

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, limits, contour-integration

Let $P_\pm$ be the Cauchy projectors defined by their action on $C^1(S^1)$ function $f$, where $S^1 = \{ \zeta \in \mathbb C \mid |z| = 1 \}$, by the rule
$$
   P_\pm f(z) = \lim\limits_{\varepsilon \to + 0} \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{|\zeta|=1}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z\cdot(1\mp\varepsilon)}d\zeta, \quad |z| = 1.
$$
So $P_\pm$ send functions on $S^1$ to functions on $S^1$. They satisfy two equalities:
\begin{align}
   \int\limits_{|z|=1}P_+f(z) \, dz &=0, \tag{1}\\
\int\limits_{|z|=1}P_- f(z)\, dz &= -\int\limits_{|z|=1}f(z) \, dz.\tag{2}
\end{align}
My question is how to prove these equalities.

---

The function
$$
    \varphi_+(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z} \, d\zeta, \quad |z| < 1,
$$
is holomorphic in the open ball $\{ z \in \mathbb C \mid |z| < 1 \}$. Then for any small $\varepsilon > 0$ the function $z \mapsto \varphi_+(z\cdot(1-\varepsilon))$ is holomorphic in the open ball $\{ z \in \mathbb C \mid |z| < (1-\varepsilon)^{-1} \}$. Hence for any small $\varepsilon > 0$ we have by the Cauchy formula
$$
    \int\limits_{|z|=1} \varphi_+(z\cdot(1-\varepsilon)) \, dz = 0
$$
and
$$
\lim\limits_{\varepsilon \to + 0}\int\limits_{|z|=1} \varphi_+(z\cdot(1-\varepsilon)) \, dz = 0.
$$
Now take into account that $\lim_{\varepsilon \to + 0} \varphi_+(z \cdot (1-\varepsilon)) = P_+ f(z)$ for $z \in S^1$. So to prove the formula (1) it is sufficient to show that
$$
\lim\limits_{\varepsilon \to + 0}\int\limits_{|z|=1} \varphi_+(z\cdot(1-\varepsilon)) \, dz = \int\limits_{|z|=1} \lim\limits_{\varepsilon \to + 0} \varphi_+(z\cdot(1-\varepsilon)) \, dz. \tag{3}
$$
If this approach is correct then the formula (2) can be proved using the same method. So the question is why the formula (3) is valid.